# Disambiguate [custom-attribute] [custom-attributes] [.net-attributes]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

I noticed that following tags are widely misused:

[custom-attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-attributes) - 1088 questions marked. According to the tag wiki it is supposed to be .NET  custom attributes, but [323 of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-attributes%2B-c%23%2B-asp.net-core%2B-asp.net-mvc%2B-asp.net-web-api%2B-asp.net%2B-.net%2B-.net-core%2B-asp.net-mvc-5%2B-asp.net-core-mvc%2B-vb.net?tab=newest) are not tagged with any of the .NET-related tags.

[custom-attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-attribute) - 57 questions marked. It is supposed to be about HTML custom attributes. It is actually used, perhaps, for every language or framework which has such a notion as "attribute".

[.net-attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-attributes) - 24 questions tagged, used correctly.

I'd propose to have only one non-synonymic tag for .NET attributes. For example:

- Retag .NET related questions marked by [custom-attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-attributes).
- Remove .NET stuff from [custom-attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-attributes) tag wiki.
- Mark [custom-attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-attribute) and [custom-attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-attributes) as synonyms.

However, [custom-attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-attribute) would still be messy. Maybe we can somehow split it or at least mention this in its tag wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with this.

We should

1. rename [custom-attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-attribute) to [html-custom-attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-custom-attributes) and
2. merge [custom-attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-attributes) into [.net-attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-attributes).

If this comes back, we should do the same and blacklist [custom-attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-attribute) and [custom-attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-attributes).